# server 2008 R2 with a NAS

Tags: windows-server-2008, authentication, network-attached-storage

I've got a server 2008 R2 running as a domain controller.  Boss wants to attach a NAS to it but want to keep it (and the files) on it available to workgroup users (Why? Boss said this was done at his previous workplace) Is this possible? If I set the NAS volume as full control, will this allow non-AD users to access the directories and files on the NAS?

What the boss wants is just to authenticate users, but allow access to all users (including those not in AD) to access the NAS.

Comment: So, authentication without any means of authorization, simply because someone said so? Your boss needs to step up his game, and realize that "we used to do things this way" is never a valid reason when it comes to IT

Answer (score 3):

If by "NAS" you mean "some external storage" and you want to share it using the server's own file sharing, you can achieve that by enabling the Guest account (disabled by default) and allowing anonymous access to the share: [How can an unauthenticated user access a windows share?](https://serverfault.com/questions/51635/how-can-an-unauthenticated-user-access-a-windows-share).

If instead by "NAS" you mean "something that can actually be connected to a network and act as a file server on its own", then you can probably configure it as you want from its own management console.